# $ \frac{\ln(x)}{x} $ show this function is not continuous uniformly

Tags: continuity, logarithms, uniform-continuity

I tried with $x = \frac1n$ and $y = \frac1{n+1}$  but it gives me nothing.
Same for $f(2x) - f(x)$.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: I know it, but is it sufficient? could you be more specific please :)?

Comment: @TsemoAristide In general, uniform continuity does not imply differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Choose $x_n = 2/n$ and $y_n = 1/n$ where $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$ but

$$\left| \frac{\ln(2/n)}{2/n} - \frac{\ln(1/n)}{1/n}\right| \to \ldots$$

An unbounded derivative is not sufficient to prove non-uniform continuity as seen with the uniformly continuous function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: And a uniformly continuous function need not be differentiable.

Comment: it tends to plus inf thus it is not Uni continue ? is that it ?

Comment: Yes -- it tends to $+\infty$ since we have the absolute value - and your conclusion is correct.  So the function is not UC on $(0,\infty)$.  It is UC on an interval $[a,\infty)$ with $a > 0$, because you can show the derivative is bounded away from $0$.

Comment: thank you RRL! it is all clear :)

Comment: @MarineGalantin: You're welcome